# Update or Insert a new value charts

Tags: javascript

```
function method() {
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
        labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
        datasets: [
            {
                label: "My First dataset",
                fill: false,
                lineTension: 0.1,
                backgroundColor: "rgba(75,192,192,0.4)",
                borderColor: "rgba(75,192,192,1)",
                borderCapStyle: 'butt',
                borderDash: [],
                borderDashOffset: 0.0,
                borderJoinStyle: 'miter',
                pointBorderColor: "rgba(75,192,192,1)",
                pointBackgroundColor: "#fff",
                pointBorderWidth: 1,
                pointHoverRadius: 5,
                pointHoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(75,192,192,1)",
                pointHoverBorderColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                pointHoverBorderWidth: 2,
                pointRadius: 1,
                pointHitRadius: 10,
                data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40],
                spanGaps: false,
            }
        ]
    },
    options: {
        responsive: false,
    }
});
```

I added a function to add a new value on the chart

```
function addvalue() {
myChart.data.labels.concat("August");
myChart.data.datasets[0].data.concat(55);
myChart.update();
```

but compiler say me "myChart is not declared" How can I draw the chart in this case?
I've just started with canvas and these charts

Comment: Read about scope,also your function has to return something

Comment: +1 to Mihai; your `myChart` variable is only available inside the `method` function, and `addvalue` cannot see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Mihai has pointed out, read deeply into MDN's documentation about [functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions) and about [scope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Scope).

Your code needs to export or make the `myChart` variable accessible to other functions. Here is the quick and dirty fix - you need to decide what is best for your app.

```
const myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
        labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
        datasets: [
            {
                label: "My First dataset",
                fill: false,
                lineTension: 0.1,
                backgroundColor: "rgba(75,192,192,0.4)",
                borderColor: "rgba(75,192,192,1)",
                borderCapStyle: 'butt',
                borderDash: [],
                borderDashOffset: 0.0,
                borderJoinStyle: 'miter',
                pointBorderColor: "rgba(75,192,192,1)",
                pointBackgroundColor: "#fff",
                pointBorderWidth: 1,
                pointHoverRadius: 5,
                pointHoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(75,192,192,1)",
                pointHoverBorderColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                pointHoverBorderWidth: 2,
                pointRadius: 1,
                pointHitRadius: 10,
                data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40],
                spanGaps: false,
            }
        ]
    },
    options: {
        responsive: false,
    }
});
```

This is global scope (not the best), but it will allow your other function to access it:

```
function addvalue() {
  // myChart is now globally accessible
  myChart.data.labels.concat("August");   
  myChart.data.datasets[0].data.concat(55);
  myChart.update();
}
```

Without knowing more context I can't specifically say to do something better (like `require` your chart into other code)

Comment: Sorry.. how can I contact u? if I can

Comment: I'm the [javascript chat room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17/javascript-types-are-lazy) atm, you can notify me of a msg you send by typing @Sean... I think.

You can also update your question to benefit others who might have the same problem.

If you feel like you need a private chat maybe we could use [https://niltalk.com/](https://niltalk.com/).

Or via a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) we could comment on that or converse via code changes (although that might not be the best for discussion how to organize an app and use dependency injection/`require`/etc.)

Comment: Yeah, I can come for a little bit.

Comment: I thought u went off. sorry. I need help with these charts.. can u create a NILTALK room?

Answer (score 0):

Scope is important and also you want to return something

```
function method() {
return new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
        labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
        datasets: [
            {
                label: "My First dataset",
                fill: false,
                lineTension: 0.1,
                backgroundColor: "rgba(75,192,192,0.4)",
                borderColor: "rgba(75,192,192,1)",
                borderCapStyle: 'butt',
                borderDash: [],
                borderDashOffset: 0.0,
                borderJoinStyle: 'miter',
                pointBorderColor: "rgba(75,192,192,1)",
                pointBackgroundColor: "#fff",
                pointBorderWidth: 1,
                pointHoverRadius: 5,
                pointHoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(75,192,192,1)",
                pointHoverBorderColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                pointHoverBorderWidth: 2,
                pointRadius: 1,
                pointHitRadius: 10,
                data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40],
                spanGaps: false,
            }
        ]
    },
    options: {
        responsive: false,
    }
});

var myChart = method();

function addvalue(myChart) {
myChart.data.labels.concat("August");
myChart.data.datasets[0].data.concat(55);
myChart.update();
return myChart;
}
```